# Problem with removeChild() function

Tags: java, 3d

I want to delete a child form a [`BranchGroup`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/BranchGroup.html)
and use the function `removeChild()`, but an exception occurred. 
This is my a part of my code; root is an branchgroup.

> //root is a branchgroup

```
public BranchGroup Creat()
{
    td.setTranslation(new Vector3d(.5f,.5f,.5f));


    tg.setTransform(td);
    tg.addChild(cube);

    td1.setTranslation(new Vector3d(x, y, z));
    tg1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    tg1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
    collision ob = new collision(cube,bounds);
    collision ob1 = new collision(cube1, bounds);
    root.addChild(ob1);  
    cube.setUserData(new String("cube"));
    tg1.setTransform(td1);
    tg1.addChild(cube1);
    root.addChild(tg);       
    root.addChild(tg1);
    //root.addChild(new ColorCube(.03));

    return root;
}

public void delete(int x)
{        
    root.removeChild(x);
}
```

this is it's exception

```
Exception occurred during Behavior execution:
javax.media.j3d.RestrictedAccessException: Group: only a BranchGroup node may be removed

    at javax.media.j3d.Group.removeChild(Group.java:217)
    at td44.Draw.delete(Draw.java:95)
    at td44.Draw$collision.Remove(Draw.java:240)
    at td44.Draw$collision.processStimulus(Draw.java:216)
    at javax.media.j3d.BehaviorScheduler.doWork(BehaviorScheduler.java:192)
    at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:275)
```

delete() function is used in another class

Comment: Added link; copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: What is the value of the parameter passed to `delete()` as formal parameter `x`?

Comment: i sure that it's parameter is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [`Group.removeChild()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/Group.html#removeChild%28javax.media.j3d.Node%29):

> Throws:
>       CapabilityNotSetException - if appropriate capability is not set and this object is part of live or compiled scene graph
>
> RestrictedAccessException - **if this group node is part of live or compiled scene graph and the child node being removed is not a BranchGroup node**

Although we haven't seen the part of the code where `delete()` is called from, this description probably fits your situation.

The solution is to wrap whatever nodes you plan to remove in a `BranchGroup`. It appears from the code that you may have attempted to do that, but in the end didn't.

```
root.addChild(new BranchGroup());
...
root.addChild(ob1);  
...
root.addChild(tg);       
root.addChild(tg1);
```

So you added an empty group to your root and a couple of standalone objects. You probably need this instead:

```
BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
root.addChild(bg);
...
bg.addChild(ob1);  
...
bg.addChild(tg);       
bg.addChild(tg1);
```

Comment: delete() function is used in another class

Comment: @mehdi Still, your problem is most likely caused by your `TransformGroup` objects being added directly to the root instead of a separate `BranchGroup`.

Comment: if each tranformgroup seperately must have a branchgroup?

Comment: @mehdi If you want them to be removed separately, then yes. Basically, `BranchGroup` is the unit you can move around in the scene, so that's how you need to design your tree.

Comment: Yes i want to delete some of transformgroup on run time so i must add a branchgroup for a transformgroup separately. is this true?